# discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions on reset nicknames

Tags: python, discord.py

I've recently created a bot to reset nicknames and the error discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 FORBIDDEN (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions popped up.

The bot has administrator rights, but cannot reset all the nicknames on the server, I assume that this is due to the fact that it cannot change my nickname, since I am the owner of the server. Is such a function feasible at all and what should I do to make it work?

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(change_nickname=True)
async def reset(ctx):
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        await member.edit(nick=None)
```

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Maxos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 229, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "A:\Py_bot\main.py", line 21, in reset
    await member.edit(nick='Боб') # reset their nickname
  File "C:\Users\Maxos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\member.py", line 880, in edit
    data = await http.edit_member(guild_id, self.id, reason=reason, **payload)
  File "C:\Users\Maxos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 738, in request
    raise Forbidden(response, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Maxos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1349, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Maxos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1023, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\Maxos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 238, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: Well, does your bot have permission to edit that member? Cause the error suggests they don't. I don't really see what your question is here.

Comment: Yes, my bot has administrator rights, I think he can't change my nickname, since I am the owner of the server, and I do not know what to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't edit the server owner. Put a try-except (or, cleaner, `suppress`) around it & move on with your loop. Alternatively, use an `if-statement` to check if the member's ID is not the owner's ID.

Comment: How to do it correctly? I am not experienced in programming. Discord.py in general I use for the first time.

Comment: This isn't related to `discord.py` at all, it's just basic Python. Googling "python catch specific exception" should tell you exactly what to do.

Comment: I mean, how do I exclude myself from this for?

Comment: Use an if-statement to check if the ID of the member is equal to the guild owner's ID